# Python 3 built-in functions and classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I am creating a `list` using below statement

`a = list('jane')`

Am I calling Python's built-in `list` function or instantiating `list` class.

My understanding is we are instantiating `list` class by passing `'jane'` as argument.

However, the Python's documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html says `list()` is built-in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs explicitly say:

> `class list([iterable])`
>
> Rather than being a function, `list` is actually a mutable sequence type

You can easily check that:

```
>>> type(list)
type
```

if it was a function, `function` would be the output provided by using `type`.

You're instantiating a `list` object the same way you'd do if you created your own class and called it. `type`'s `__call__` is essentially getting invoked and sets up your instance so, though they aren't a function per se, they are callable.

---

The fact that they are listed in that specific section is probably for convenience, it might be confusing but reading the description of it is supposed to disambiguate this.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered by the [very documentation page you mention](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list):

> `class list([iterable])`
>   Rather than being a function, [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) is actually a mutable sequence type, as documented in [Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list) and [Sequence Types — list, tuple, range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).

In Python, both classes and functions are callable, so in practice, you can treat them alike.

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a list.

> `class list([iterable])`
>   Rather than being a function, list is actually a mutable sequence type, as documented in Lists and Sequence Types — list, tuple, range.